# Why is my desctruct method being called too early?

Tags: php, pdo

I have simplified my class for better understanding. Why is method2 giving me error that self::$dbconn is null? When remove __desctruc() it works fine?

I am calling it like so:

```
$test = new TestCtrl();
$test->getList(123);
```

...

```
class TestCtrl {

        private static $dbconn;

        function __construct(){
            self::$dbconn = 'assume this is my db connection...';
        }

        function __destruct() {
            self::$dbconn = null;
        }

        private function method1($contact){
            $metas = self::method2();
            return $metas;
        }
        private static function method2(){

            $res = self::$dbconn;
            return $res;
        }

        public function getList($contact){
            return self::method1($contact);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Show how your calling it also why are you using static when the class is not static?

Comment: I'm assuming you checked your constructor was indeed setting `self::$dbconn` to something and not `null`?

Comment: yeah sure... but you can test by modifying code a bit :-)

Comment: Why are you even destroying your db connection in the first place? It's one of the worst things you can do, it really is no matter how unlikely or illogical it may sound.

Comment: well to free memory!? Is this wrong?

Comment: When the script ends the connection will be closed. There really is no reason to close it yourself as @N.B. said.

Comment: If PHP-FPM is used to serve PHP, and it should be because it's 2018 and stupidities like mod_php shouldn't be used in your wildest dreams, then explicitly closing the connection does no good. PHP-FPM will attempt to keep resources active because it doesn't kill the process handling the request. That means you open the connection to db once, use multiple times. It saves time and increases performance. Closing the connection only to open it on next request is just wasteful, pointless and doesn't do any good whatsoever in any imaginable scenario. Just don't do it.

Comment: Also, you are freeing what memory? How much of it? Where did you even get the idea you're freeing memory? For WHAT?! There you go, a clear example how premature optimization is bad. Your assumption is wrong. Your action is hurtful. You ran into a problem that you're not supposed to have. Why? Because you wanted to free memory. Is the memory even wasted? Do you understand the execution model of a PHP script at all? You assumed, you didn't check, you ran into a problem and even if you get it working - it's just going to make the whole thing work slower. 0 gain, infinite loss.

Comment: Well thanks for your very extensive response, however i am not asking you about your opinion on PHP-FPM, nor is it given in my example that i am attempting to reopen the connection after its closes. Further more i am not sure why  you very arrogantly assume i didn’t test. To be honest your answer is rather a very rude attempt to gain some profile which you probably miss in real life... this is very sad, but the most embarrassing thing is that you didn’t even try to answer my question. So i assume you don’t know!? Thanks anyway :-)

Answer (score 0):

Because you've declared $dbconn as static it is getting set to its original value between calls.  Change it to a non-static variable and it should work fine.

Comment: how you mean un-static? as you see the methods in which this static variable is used are also static, therefore $dbconn also have to be static, am I misunderstanding?